# Immutable C++ container class

Tags: c++, stl

Say that I have a C++ class, `Container`, that contains some elements of type `Element`.  For various reasons, it is inefficient, undesirable, unnecessary, impractical, and/or impossible (1) to modify or replace the contents after construction.  Something along the lines of `const std::list<const Element>` (2).

`Container` can meet many requirements of the STL's "container" and "sequence" concepts.  It can provide the various types like `value_type`, `reference`, etc.  It can provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, a `const_iterator` type, `begin() const`, `end() const`, `size`, `empty`, all the comparison operators, and maybe some of `rbegin() const`, `rend() const`, `front()`, `back()`, `operator[]()`, and `at()`.

However, `Container` can't provide `insert`, `erase`, `clear`, `push_front`, `push_back`, non-const `front`, non-const `back`, non-const `operator[]`, or non-const `at` with the expected semantics.  So it appears that `Container` can't qualify as a "sequence".  Further, `Container` can't provide `operator=`, and `swap`, and it can't provide an `iterator` type that points to a non-const element.  So, it can't even qualify as a "container".

Is there some less-capable STL concept that `Container` meets?  Is there a "read-only container" or an "immutable container"?

If `Container` doesn't meet any defined level of conformance, is there value in partial conformance?  Is is misleading to make it look like a "container", when it doesn't qualify?  Is there a concise, unambiguous way that I can document the conformance so that I don't have to explicitly document the conforming semantics?  And similarly, a way to document it so that future users know they can take advantage of read-only generic code, but don't expect mutating algorithms to work?

What do I get if I relax the problem so `Container` is Assignable (but its elements are not)?  At that point, `operator=` and `swap` are possible, but dereferencing `iterator` still returns a `const Element`.  Does `Container` now qualify as a "container"?

`const std::list<T>` has approximately the same interface as `Container`.  Does that mean it is neither a "container" nor a "sequence"?

Footnote (1) I have use cases that cover this whole spectrum.  I have a would-be-container class that adapts some read-only data, so it has to be immutable.  I have a would-be-container that generates its own contents as needed, so it's mutable but you can't replace elements the way the STL requires.  I yet have another would-be-container that stores its elements in a way that would make `insert()` so slow that it would never be useful.  And finally, I have a string that stores text in UTF-8 while exposing a code-point oriented interface; a mutable implementation is possible but completely unnecessary.

Footnote (2) This is just for illustration.  I'm pretty sure `std::list` requires an assignable element type.

Comment: How do you put the initial elements into the container?

Comment: @FredOverflow Differently for each of my use cases.  For the adapter, I am given the adapted container already populated, and my class just stores a pointer to it.  The self-populating container creates its elements as they are requested base upon some mutable parameters.  The container where generic STL-compliant insert is too slow has efficient non-STL-compliant methods for insertion.  And the UTF-8 string is just given a byte array or iterator range in its constructor.

Comment: Obvious solutions are to use iterators, or move them from a mutable container to the immutable `Container`.

Comment: What about structural sharing using Stratified B-Trees?

Answer (score 2):

The STL doesn't define any lesser concepts; mostly because the idea of `const` is usually expressed on a per-iterator or per-reference level, not on a per-class level.

You shouldn't provide `iterator` with unexpected semantics, only provide `const_iterator`. This allows client code to fail in the most logical place (with the most readable error message) if they make a mistake.

Possibly the easiest way to do it would be to encapsulate it and prevent all non-const aliases.

```
class example {
    std::list<sometype> stuff;
public:
    void Process(...) { ... }
    const std::list<sometype>& Results() { return stuff; }
};
```

Now any client code knows exactly what they can do with the return value of Results- nada that requires mutation.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your object can provider a conforming const_iterator it doesn't have to have anything else. It should be pretty easy to implement this on your container class.

(If applicable, look at the Boost.Iterators library; it has iterator_facade and iterator_adaptor classes to help you with the nitty-gritty details)