# C++ equivalent to an immutable container

Tags: c++, collections, immutability

A recent discussion led me to the question:

*Do immutable containers exist in C++?* Alternately, since C++ prefers iterators to generalized containers, do immutable iterators exist?

I'm talking about something like the equivalent of Guava's [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) or the built-in `Collections.unmodifiable*` methods. To be clear, those two types of collections are very different - the former is inherently immutable, while the latter is only immutable by actors who get the unmodifiable reference, but is potentially modifiable by actors who have access to the unwrapped object.

I'm interested to know if there is a standardized (actual or de-facto, as in Guava) equivalent to `ImmutableCollection`:

- A collection which can never be modified, by any actor. Additionally, functions which take this type are providing documentation that they cannot and will not modify such collections received as arguments, or returned as return values.

or to `ret ro = Colletions.unmodifiableCollection(orginalCollection)` (and related methods):

- Subtly different than the above, this is a *view* of the original collection, which is modifiable by anyone who has the `originalCollection` but not by anyone with the return value `ro`. Usually it is implemented by wrapping the original collection in a proxy that prevents any modification, but other implementations are possible.

I'm well aware of `const std::iterator` and friends, but this is very different - it ensures that the a caller can pass an object to a callee, and the object won't modify it, but it does not guarantee to the callee that the object won't be modified.

Now I'm a long-time C++ user here, although admittedly not in the last 5 years, and I couldn't come up with the obvious equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

There's a project called immer which might be able to handle this  this need:

*"immutable and persistent data structures for C++"*

https://github.com/arximboldi/immer

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such Container in C++, but its really **easy** to do such on two levels... **First** is being `const` correct with the object's class you want to store, **Second** is by using a const reference or pointer to the container you want. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Cow {
  public:
  Cow() : name("default") {}
  Cow(string Name) : name(Name) {}

  string shout() const { return name; }

  private:
  string name;
};

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<const Cow>> mc;
    Cow mm("Lol");
    mc.push_back(make_unique<const Cow>(Cow()));
    mc.push_back(make_unique<const Cow>(Cow("haha")));
    mc.push_back(make_unique<const Cow>(mm));

    const auto& mcc = mc;  //here, your immutable reference

    for(auto& x : mcc)
        cout << x.get()->shout() << " - - ";
    return 0;
}
```

I am using a `std::unique_ptr` here because, its almost certainly useless to use `vector<const Cow> mc`.

This portion, `const auto& mcc = mc;` from here, take `mcc` *as* your immutable container... You can't add or modify it's elements via any legal means, except of cause casting away `const`...

This applies to all other containers I know.

Still on Stackoverflow, See [Immutable C++ container class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478866/immutable-c-container-class) and [Immutable container with mutable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797483/immutable-container-with-mutable-content)

A side note: Also, if the class you want to use is `const` incorrect, create a cheap wrapper class that is `const` correct then use the wrapper.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm after. The `mcc` object is entirely mutable, just not by callers who get an `mcc` reference! In particular, `mcc` is mutable since `mc` is mutable. Imagine a method that took a `const Cow` parameter, assumed it was immutable, and cached state such as the name across various cow objects. It would fail in the example above if the name of cow was changed.

Comment: That was why I said it requires two levels of work from you... `Cow` must be `const` correct. And if you don't want `Cow` to ever change state after creation, then don't change it... In my example, there's absolutely no way to change `Cow`'s name after construction... If your class has functions that can mutate it, or mutable members, then you'll have to provide a `const` correct wrapper ... Or Am I still missing something?

Comment: You are still missing something - `Cow` happens to be an immutable object (it has no mutating methods at all), but imagine it mutable but const correct - a caller could pass it to any method even as a `const` Cow and it would still be mutable. My question is about collections in particular, and whether immutable collections exist in C++. It's already clear to be that it's possible to create "constant Cow" objects.

Comment: Ok, but if you already know `Cow` is `const` correct but mutable (`const` incorrect), why don't you just provide a `const` correct wrapper?. But answering your reiterated question. There is no "such" container that I know of, neither have I come across one in C++, C++'s notion of `const` is quite different Java's AFAIK

Comment: I'm missing your point. Let's assume every object is const-correct for the purposes of my argument. The `const` specifier is then useful to the caller (who knows that `const` objects cannot be modified by the callee). It is useless to the _calleee_, however, who doesn't know if a non-constant object has been trivially converted to `const` by the caller (or, indeed, any of the indirect callers), or whether the object is truly immutable. The point is that cost means "you can't modify the object" rather than "the object cannot be modified".

Comment: You last statement is correct if based on the fact that C++ provides `const` and also the `const_cast` faciity. Other than that, `const` qualification isn't useless to the callee... The compiler will ensure the callee doesn't modify the `const&` parameter

Comment: Right. That's why I'm asking about "immutable" connections. _Immutable_ here means: will never be modified, ever. It doesn't mean "can't be modified, outside of `const_cast` usage, within the current context", which is what C++ seems to offer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104015/discussion-between-beeonrope-and-whiztim).